# On attaching CentOS root volume with AWS marketplace code to other CentOS EC2 instance, the other instance boots up using the attached root volume

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, centos6.5

I screwed up root volume of my system in ec2 instance so I attached root volume of the  instance to other ec2 instance so that I could access the bad root volume and rectify my error. When I start the other instance, the screwed up root volume becomes the root volume of the instance. I attached the volume as /dev/sdb (kernel changed it to /dev/xvdf )  and the instance original root volume is at /dev/sda (kernel changed it to /dev/xvde ). So kernel should load /dev/xvde as root filesystem but its loading scrwed up root volume (/dev/xvdf) .

The snippet of system logs of the system is as following:

dracut: Starting plymouth daemon

xlblk_init: register_blkdev major: 202

blkfront: xvdf: barriers disabled

xvdf: unknown partition table

blkfront: xvde: barriers disabled

xvde: unknown partition table

EXT4-fs (xvdf): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts:

dracut: Mounted root filesystem /dev/xvdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OR

The simple way is to attach Centos root volume to a amazon linux machine and fix the issue. Don't attach Centos root volume to another ec2 instance running Centos.
Centos in AWS marketplace have "centos" as label for root volume . So when we attach centos root volume to another centos machine, AWS gets confused as to which root volume to mount and anomaly happens.

Answer (score 1):

As the screwed up root volume and the original instance root volume has the same label attached to the volume partition (in my case my OS is centos6.5 and the label is centos_root ) , so we have to change the label of our instance so that next time it boots it doesn't look for  label centos_root and instead it will look for our changed label.

First, change the root volume partition label by the command
ex.  e2label /dev/xvde your_label  ,
here /dev/xvde is the root partition

Second, change the label in "/etc/fstab and /boot/grub/grub.conf" with your_label.

Third, Stop the instance

Fourth, Attched the screwed up root volume to the instance

Fifth, Start the instance

Sixth, Voila now you can see the screwed up root volume partition and mount it to some mount point to fix your issue .

Comment: @Vorsprung     : Hey it works for me this way, Have you used the same way to solved it

Comment: no but it's a great tip, I will be remembering labels if I face this kind of problem

Answer (score 0):

deattach the "screwed up" volume from the other ec2 instance

boot the other instance normally

attach the EBS to the running instance see
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html

do `fdisk -l` as root and find the device name of the new instance

make a "mount point" (a directory) and mount the desired disk partition on it

once it is fixed, use the `umount` command on the mount point and then deattach
the volume

If the AMI has a marketplace code try the steps given in this answer https://serverfault.com/questions/522173/aws-vol-xxxxxxx-with-marketplace-codes-may-not-be-attached-as-as-secondary-dev

Comment: But the  "screwed up" volume has an AWS Marketplace product code.
So volume can only be attached to a stopped instance.

Comment: I think  attaching higher letter also doesn't help because still my logs shows it is using the new root volume to boot up :                                                                 dracut: Starting plymouth daemon
xlblk_init: register_blkdev major: 202 
blkfront: xvdl: barriers disabled
 xvdl: unknown partition table
blkfront: xvde: barriers disabled
 xvde: unknown partition table
EXT4-fs (xvdl): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
_**`dracut: Mounted root filesystem /dev/xvdl`**_

Comment: Try the steps given in this answer http://serverfault.com/questions/522173/aws-vol-xxxxxxx-with-marketplace-codes-may-not-be-attached-as-as-secondary-dev

Answer (score 0):

PSA: don't use CentOS in AWS.

You can no longer attach a root volume for a CentOS instance to another instance. This is by design, to prevent people from circumventing licensing agreements. Even though CentOS is technically free, because it's a marketplace AMI, the rule applies. It's a good rule in general, but it makes recovery of a failed configuration impossible.

Use Amazon Linux. It's basically CentOS anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the tables on the bootloader.

If the working instance insists on booting the broken volume when attached as a data volume (`/dev/xvd[f-p]`), then a simple hack you can try is to turn things around and attach a working root volume to the broken instance as a data volume.

This has worked to recover a broken CentOS 7 root volume using a root volume borrowed from a good instance. Both instances were built from the same Marketplace AMI and there were no complaints about attaching the marketplace AMI as a data volume. The system booted the good volume instead of the broken volume. (Even though the broken volume still showed up in its original device position at `/dev/xvda1`, with the booted volume at `/dev/xvdf1`.)

If you get `wrong fs type, ...` when then mounting the broken volume, check for label collision:

```
# blkid
/dev/xvda1: UUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/xvdf1: UUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="xfs"
```

You can mount without checking UUIDs with:

```
mount -o nouuid /dev/xvda1 /some/where
```

YMMV.